# Vue Pinia doesn't update reactive state more than once

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

In my vue application, the structure is like this:
App.vue
-GroupWrapper
--GroupListing
-PeopleWrapper
--PeopleListing
-ConversationWrapper

I have a user store that uses pinia, and my main use of it is calling user.findChats() in the App.vue

App.vue

```
import { useChatStore } from './stores/chat'
import { useUserStore } from './stores/user'

const chat = useChatStore()
const user = useUserStore()

chat.findChats();
```

where it finds all the chats and if it's of the type "dm" it adds it to the dm_chats array and if it's the type "gm" it adds it to the gm_chats array,

chat.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { db } from '../firebase'
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { useUserStore } from './user'

export const useChatStore = defineStore('chat', {
  state: () => ({
    dm_chats: [],
    gm_chats: [],
    user: useUserStore(),
  }),
  actions: {
    async findChats(id) {
      const chatsRef = collection(db, 'chats')
      const q = query(chatsRef, where('chat_users', 'array-contains', this.user.id))
      await getDocs(q).then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((docu) => {
          if (docu.data().type == 'dm') {
            this.dm_chats.push(docu.id)
          } else {
            this.gm_chats.push(docu.id)
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Where the dm_chats should be displayed in a v-for in PeopleListing

PeopleWrapper.vue

```
<script setup>
import peopleListing from './people-listing.vue'
import { useChatStore } from '../../stores/chat'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';

const chat = useChatStore()
const { dm_chats: chats } = storeToRefs(chat)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      Direct Chats
    </div>
    <div>
      <peopleListing v-for="dm_chat in chats" :dm_chat="dm_chat" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the same for gm_chats in GroupListing,

However after for looping over the array, the only update on screen is once, only when it fetches from firestore the document for a chat of type "gm", even tho when using Vue Devtools or console.log, the dm_chat and gm_chat are properly populated, it's just not updating them.

What I've tried was:

- Unified both stores into one file
- Changing the pinia syntax from option to setup
- Using reactive in the array when it was setup
- Using computed instead of storeToRefs both in setup and options syntax, I even tried using both at the same time.
- Tried the $subscribe method
- Tried the vue watch method

After all that, it had the same result.
Now this is probably me missing something very basic, but I can't for the life of me find out what it is. This also isn't with just the dm_chats or the gm_chats, this is with every other variable in both the user and chat stores. So if anyone could let me know what I'm missing, I'd be super thankful.

Comment: `it's just not updating them` - what isn't? you call `chat.findChats();` once - what makes you think that will run again?

Comment: It's not that I want it to run again. The function call isn't updating the state as its supposed to, where it should populate the arrays with information from the firebase query and then the screen should be reactively updated to reflect the received info. Instead it only updates the view once with the first result, and that's it, no other updates at all no matter what I try.

Comment: so, you want to call `chat.findChats();` once, and the result is dm_chats and gm_chats being "reactive" with the data in a database that could be somewhere half way across the planet without calling `chat.findChats()` again?

Comment: findChats is the starting function to get all the chats that are available, I'm just fetching the reference to the recent chats and displaying the result, my point is that the result isn't getting displayed at all, whether I fetch it once or twice it doesn't matter if it doesn't get shown in the vue components.

Comment: oh ... I thought `only update on screen is once` meant that it DOES show something - so which code is supposed to keep updating the chat as new messages come in? it seems you've forgotten to show that

Comment: you also didn't show the code for `peopleListing`  component - perhaps you did something wrong in there - but still, other than initial load, your `dm_chats` and `gm_chats` will never change with the code you've written

Answer (score -1):

please don't call the store another store's state, remove this  `user: useUserStore(),`

use instead of this calling inside action:

`async findChats(id) { const user = userStore() }`

Comment: This isn't the solution. It's acceptable to use a store both ways, as long as this doesn't cause race conditions